# How to remove blank space on top of page?

Tags: html, css

I'm redoing my entire website, because I'm trying to get away from my "just-learning" style of page. One thing I noticed was that there is a large blank gap that shows up as soon as the page has finished loading. [Here](http://joeybabcock.me) is a link to my website. Upon using inspect element in chrome, I see that the white space is composed of

```
"
    &nbsp;"
```

characters. This happens in all browsers available for me to test it in.

Edit1:
In an attempt to show that I tried,
I've tried setting the body in the css to `margin: 0`
and removing all css that is related to the top.

Comment: Are you creating your website in notepad or an application such as Dreamweaver?

Comment: Could you post your code without commented out sections and other garbage that's in your page's source?

Comment: I'm removing all unnecessary comments now

Comment: You don't have to do that: you can post the relevant code bits here

Comment: I needed to remove the 100+ lines of useless comments that I thought might be useful later. threefouronesixonethree how might I fix it?

Comment: I can't find the &nbsp; anywhere threefour? do you know what line it's on?

Comment: as a word of caution... this page you have created has a SEVERE load time issue...

Comment: yes, i had an ip webcam on it :) that just goes to show it is time for me to redo it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without code it is hard to determine... you could try a css reset on the body...

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
```

Also, after you edited the code, i see a secondary `}` after your body edit.

Comment: thanks again for you're help, it was actually some php i had forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

your html is not valid. this was prepared `&nbsp;`

table in html is written like this:

```
<table> <!-- start table -->
     <tr> <!-- start table row -->
           <td></td> <!-- table cell-->
     </tr> <!-- end table row -->
</table> <!-- end table -->
```